# python functions call in javascript autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, python

this is my views.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/autocomplete')

*def get_contacts():*

    cat_list = []
    cat_list = contact.objects.all()
    return dumps(cat_list)
```

and this is my js

function showDialog()
{

```
$("#dialog").dialog(

{
    width: 600,
    height: 400,

});

$.ajax({
    url:'{{url_for("autocomplete")}}'
}).done(function(data){
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
            source: data
        });
});
```

}

when I'm trying to run this i give the following error

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/share_win/%7B%7Burl_for(%22autocomplete%22)%7D%7D 404 (NOT FOUND)

Any idea?

Comment: Are you positive that you've passed your Javascript file through Jinja?

Comment: is jinja browser depended??? I got this error when I run on chrome, but now when i run it on fiirefox i got this  Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is coming from here:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'{{url_for("autocomplete")}}'
})
```

The `url_for` method requires the name of the function for the desired route rather than physical route.

To fix this, you can either do:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'{{url_for("get_contacts")}}'
})
```

or if your Javascript is in a JS file, then do the following:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/autocomplete'
})
```

Comment: Yep my javascript is in JS file and after editing it as you said i got this GET 127.0.0.1:8000/autocomplete 404 (NOT FOUND)

Comment: @gjivanya It may be due to how you have your flask project set up. How are you running the flask app?

Comment: python manage.py runserver . Should I do something additional if I'm using flask in my project ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error.

It worked when the javascript was in the html file ( base.html in my case), but not when it was in a separate file I called dgmain.js.

I put the javascript in my template (create_product.html) in the {% block scripts %} and it works there.

It seems like it needs to be in the template, not in a seperate .js file when jinja2 is being used.